# LinqtoXML: Getting element values

Tags: linq-to-xml

I can't quite get my query correct.  Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FileTypes>
  <File type="photo">
    <Extension>.jpg</Extension>
    <Extension>.gif</Extension>
  </File>
  <File type="document">
    <Extension>.pdf</Extension>
  </File>
  <File type="video">
   <Extension>.flv</Extension>
  </File>
</FileTypes>
```

I would like to extract the extensions to a string array for a given file type.  This is what I have so far:

```
var query = from m in _UploadFileTypes.Elements("FileTypes").Elements("File")
    where m.Attribute("type").Value.ToUpper() == fileTypeFilter
    select m.Elements("Extension");

foreach (var item in query)
{
    //item.ToString() does not yield the correct value...
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = 
    from file in _UploadFileTypes.Root.Elements("File")
    let typeAttrib = file.Attribute("type")
    where 
        typeAttribute != null 
        && typeAttribute.Value.ToUpper() == fileTypeFilter
    from extension in file.Elements("Extension")
    select extension.Value;
foreach (var extension in query)
{
    // extension is the string content of the Extension element
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this will give a NullReferenceException if a File element has no type attribute. (Which may not matter depending on the schema.) If that matters, you could change the where to:
   let typeAttribute = file.Attribute("type")
   where typeAttribute != null && typeAttribute.Value.ToUpper() == fileTypeFilter

Comment: That's only giving me the first element... for example, it's only returning .jpg in the photo type... it's not including both extensions.

Comment: Change Element("Extension") to Elements("Extension") to get all values.

Comment: Oops, I missed that you could have multiple extensions.  Time to modify it again.

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't realize you could use from clauses twice.  I am a noobie at LinqToXML, but I am happy because I was somewhat close.

Answer (score 1):

@Jacob gave a great answer, but I believe simply using `item.Value` instead of `item.ToString` will give the value you're looking for using the code you had.

You can use IntelliSense to hover over your `query` to see that it's items are of type XElement. @Jacob's answer contains the `.Value` within the query, so in his version `query` contains strings.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  When I revert back to my original code item is a collection of XElements.  It's almost like I need to have nested foreach loops.  However, I know that there will only be one collection of elements with the specified attributes.  It's almost like I need the original query to return a single collection of XElements so I can recurse through them instead of returning a collection of a collection.